# Mail chimp CURL - (23) Failed writing body

Tags: curl, mailchimp

I am trying to add a member to my mail chimp list (API 3.0). I've followed the docs and tutorials to the letter. After much debugging, I'm at a wall with this issue.

Here is my request (edited as per feedback):

```
curl -H "Authorisation:apikeyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-us12" -d "{\"email_address\":\"abc@xyz.com\",\"status\":\"subscribed\"}" "https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/a1b2c3d4e5/members" | json
```

and here is what terminal is returning

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   193  100   193    0     0    438      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   439
(23) Failed writing body
```

So I guess there are two things here that are confusing me:

```
-bash: json: command not found
```

and

```
(23) Failed writing body
```

Comment: hope those are not the actual quote marks your using

Comment: I'm thinking they are. There are some major escaping problems here.

Comment: do people program in MS Word?

Comment: Well I write all my code in Microsoft Works 7.

Comment: oh god i remember works, came free with the 486 :)

Comment: Thank you guys. I have changed the quotes but it wasn't the issue, sadly.

Comment: I see you have updated your question to clearly show that you are trying to pipe the output of the whole operation to a command called `json`. what is your goal with that?

Comment: Hi jeff, again, appreciate your time. Somewhat embarrassingly I have the piped JSON at the end because this is what the mailchimp api docs suggested.

Comment: you don't have such a command installed, which is why you're getting `-bash: json: command not found`, so remove that.

Comment: screen grab of mail chimp tutorial: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/egqtj2d3palfojz/Screenshot%202016-04-26%2023.05.06.png?dl=0)

Comment: ok thanks, I have removed that and now getting an error that says YOUR REQUEST DID NOT INCLUDE AN API KEY. Somewhat frustrating is this, given that I'm following their own docs to the letter.

Comment: try the format in their example [here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#create-post_lists_list_id_members), it's a little more explicit and shows how to use the auth key with a `--user` option

Comment: D'oh. The problem was in the spelling of "authorisation". I have spelled it with an S and the USA spelling requires a Z - Authorization.

Comment: Also, I really hope this isn't your real API key. :(

Comment: Hi, i looked back over all the revisions and I'm pretty certain I didn't put my actual API key in here.

Answer (score 1):

are you supposed to have a pipe `|` at the end of your URL `/members|json`?

I'm guessing it's supposed to be a slash `/` instead `/members/json`

```
curl -H "Authorisation:apices<APIKEY>" -d "{"email_address":"test@test.com","status":"subscribed"}" https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<LIST-ID>/members/json
```

Or if that's right, then try wrapping the URL in double quotes `"`

```
curl -H "Authorisation:apices<APIKEY>" -d "{"email_address":"test@test.com","status":"subscribed"}" "https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<LIST-ID>/members|json"
```

And you might need to be using single quotes `'` to wrap your data

```
curl -H "Authorisation:apices<APIKEY>" -d '{"email_address":"test@test.com","status":"subscribed"}' "https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<LIST-ID>/members|json"
```

Or escaping those inner double quotes `\"` instead

```
 curl -H "Authorisation:apices<APIKEY>" -d "{\"email_address\":\"test@test.com\",\"status\":\"subscribed\"}" "https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<LIST-ID>/members|json"
```

And in case you didn't catch [@Dagon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876122/mail-chimp-curl-23-failed-writing-body#comment-61318976), I replaced all your squirrely quotes `“` with real ones `"`

Comment: yup clearly nix is trying to output to "json" which is not a nix program

Comment: Thank you very much for your time in constructing this answer. Unfortunately I have tried everything and the result is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution to this specific problem was in the spelling of "Authorisation". The Mailchimp API seems to need the American spelling, which is "Authorzation" - with a "Z".

(also I didn't need "| json")

Comment: It's a standardized HTTP header, it needs to be spelled like this always!